# Backup con errores

Tags: wordpress

Hace poco comence en el mundo de Wordpress y estoy tratando de sumar puntos con las empresas que voy laburando.
Resulta que una de estas, cambio de hosting completamente asi que la web (que no realice yo ni puedo contactar a quien la hizo) cayo y volvieron a levantar el dominio en otro Hosting, a lo que me pidieron si podia subir la web nuevamente..
La primer alternativa que probe es con el All in one Migration, tenia un backup hecho asi que intente subirlo varias veces, sin exito, hasta que pude subirla pero tengo un problema con el Logo Principal, me aparece de esta forma 
[image: Menu incorrecto]

Cuando en realidad deberia aparecer asi.. 
[image: Menu Correcto]

Realmente se muy poco de codigo, soy mas de la parte intuitiva de wp, revise todas las formas posibles de acomodarlo dentro de mis conocimientos, pero nada!
A alguien se le ocurre que pueda ser que no me deje poner el logo como estaba originalmente?.

La otra opción que empece a pensar es realizar otro tipo de backup, tengo un Winrar con el backup de la web completa + dump SQL. Esto los realizaron gente de sistema ajena a mi, pero tengo acceso a esos archivos. Existe alguna guia o forma de subir manualmente todo y que funcione tal cual estaba anteriormente? (Plugins, entradas, etc).
Intente realizarlo en local, pero hasta ahora no logre que levante la web.
Desde ya muchas gracias y ojala alguien pueda darme una mano!

Comment: La url que estás usando es diferente a la original?

Comment: No, es el mismo dominio! En principio supuse que mediante el All in One MIgration me iba a funcionar todo de una, y efectivamente funciona todo menos ese logo que me quedo colgado..

Answer (score 1):

En principio, con una copia del sistema de directorios de **Wordpress** y una de la **Base de Datos** debería valerte. Si el plugin que has usado con la migración provoca que algunos recursos (como imágenes) no se puedan visualizar correctamente es muy posible que no haya hecho todo los cambios necesarios a nivel de **Base de Datos**, más concretamente a nivel de rutas.

Para asegurarme suelo realizar cuatro **updates** de **MySQL** que suelen ser suficientes para que todos los recursos apunten al nuevo dominio:

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = REPLACE ( option_value, 'http://dominioantiguo.com', 'http://www.dominionuevo.com' );

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = REPLACE ( guid, 'http://www.dominioantiguo.com', 'http://www.dominionuevo.com' );

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE ( post_content, 'http://www.dominioantiguo.com', 'http://www.dominionuevo.com' );

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = REPLACE ( meta_value, 'http://www.dominioantiguo.com', 'http://www.dominionuevo.com' );
```

Para poder realizar estas sentencias necesitas acceso a la **Base de Datos** del servidor Web donde tengas alojado tu sitio.

Otra opción sería volver a subir el logo que no te funciona a tus **Medios** y volver a cargar la imagen en donde corresponda (dependiendo del Tema de Wordpress tendrás que hacerlo desde una u otra sección, pero todos los Temas suelen tener una interfaz para cargar el logo de tu sitio).

**EDIT**

A raíz de visitar tu Sitio he visto que la ruta a tus imágenes es:

> http://hotelmajestic.com.ar/wp-content/uploads...

Pero la de tu logo es:

> http://www.hotelmajestic.com.ar/v02/wp-content/uploads...

En ella veo dos posibles fallos: el uso del subdominio **www** (uso que no haces en los otros enlaces que tienes) y el uso del directorio **v02** que se encuentra fuera del que **Wordpress** usa por defecto para sus recursos.

**EDIT 2**

Si el logo se ha subido mediante las opciones de la plantilla, debería haber quedado registrada su ruta en la tabla `wp_options`, pero para asegurarnos podríamos ejecutar los siguientes updates:

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = REPLACE ( option_value, 'http://www.hotelmajestic.com.ar/v02/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/logo-simple.gif', 'ruta absoluta de donde tienes almacenado el logo despues de subirlo de nuevo a medios' );

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = REPLACE ( guid, 'http://www.hotelmajestic.com.ar/v02/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/logo-simple.gif', 'ruta absoluta de donde tienes almacenado el logo despues de subirlo de nuevo a medios' );

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE ( post_content, 'http://www.hotelmajestic.com.ar/v02/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/logo-simple.gif', 'ruta absoluta de donde tienes almacenado el logo despues de subirlo de nuevo a medios' );

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = REPLACE ( meta_value, 'http://www.hotelmajestic.com.ar/v02/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/logo-simple.gif', 'ruta absoluta de donde tienes almacenado el logo despues de subirlo de nuevo a medios' );
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por tu respuesta desde ya.. me surgen un par de dudas dentro de la misma.
Los cuatro updates de MySQL se realizan directamente en la base de datos, agrego esas lineas modificando los datos y listo no? O tengo que buscar donde esten esos datos y modificarlos?

Y con el tema de la ubicacion del logo si, yo note esa diferencia,el tema es que yo unicamente subi el archivo .wpress del Plugin, no se como estaba la web anteriormente, ni siquiera se si usaban subdominios ni nada de eso..
Y desde el FTP subi el archivo del logo, a la carpeta que indicada pero no funciono..

Comment: Tambien algo raro que sucede es que desde el propio cPanel, entrando a las carpetas de archivos no puedo ver los archivos del wordpress, pero desde el FTP si.. sinceramente nunca habia visto semejante lio en una web jaja.
Y desde el mismo wordpress busque dentro del tema para subir el logo nuevamente, pero no puedo acceder a modificar nada mas que el menu, por ningun lado aparece el bendito logo

Comment: Si me dices el nombre del Tema que estás usando igual se puede averiguar algo. Las sentencias de SQL que te puse no sirven de nada cuando el problema parece no depender del dominio, si no del sistema de directorios que tienes en tu servidor Web.

Comment: Estos son los unicos datos del Tema que esta utilizando la web!
-
Theme Name: Majestic
Theme URI: 
Author: Curly Themes
Author URI: 
Description: Child Theme for Leisure
Version: 1
Template: leisure

Comment: Edité mi respuesta de nuevo para lanzar una serie de sentencias que buscarían la ruta erronea del logo para cambiarla por la ruta buena. Ten en cuenta que debes 'sustituir ruta absoluta de donde tienes almacenado el logo despues de subirlo de nuevo a medios' por la ruta que corresponda.

Answer (score 0):

Yo revisaria la ruta de la imagen.

http://hotelmajestic.com.ar/v02/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/logo-simple.gif

Ya que el mensaje que te da cuando vas a esta ruta es que no se encuentra la página.

Gracias.

Comment: Te agradezco tu respuesta! verifique la ruta de la imagen desde el FTP e incluso la volvi a subir pero sigue sin aparecer, tampoco entiendo porque aparece ese logo como /v02/wp-content/..  si en el FTP no existe la carpeta v02..

Comment: A raiz de este pensamiento que te digo de que no existe esa carpeta, como puedo modificar la ruta de esa imagen para que apunte a /wp-content/... directamente sin ese v02? Hay alguna forma?

Comment: Supongo que accedes a la página de wordpress con usuario y contraseña, y desde allí modificas los textos e imagenes. Accede a la administración de wordpress y busca donde esta ubicado el logo-simple.